# Get-WinEvent -filterXPath stopped working

Tags: windows, powershell, xpath, event-log

I am trying to do some event querying using `Get-WinEvent` and XPath.  I was successfully testing it before I left work yesterday, but today, no matter what I try, it keeps telling me that there are no matching events.

I still have the PowerShell window open from yesterday with the successful query, and even repeating the *same commands* via shell history is returning nothing.

I can't get any XPath queries to work.  Simple example, this returns thousands of event records:

```
$EventFilter = @{ 
          Logname      = 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational'
          ProviderName = "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler"
          Id           = 129
       }
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $EventFilter -verbose
```

But the following claims `No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.`:

```
[xml]$XPath = @"
  <QueryList>
    <Query Id="0" Path="microsoft-windows-taskscheduler/operational">
      <Select Path="microsoft-windows-taskscheduler/operational">*
        [System/Provider[@Name='microsoft-windows-taskscheduler'] and
        (System/EventID=129)]
      </Select>
    </Query>
  </QueryList>
"@
Get-WinEvent -logname 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational' -FilterXPath $XPath
```

**NOTE:** I am NOT using invalid queries.  The xml above is simply reformatted from the query (constructed and) displayed from the `-verbose` switch on the first one.  In the end, I need to use XPath because `-FilterHashtable` is too limited, but I even can't get the simple XPath queries to work.

I'm starting to pull my hair out on this.  What could possibly prevent this from working today when it worked before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different (but similar) parameters you can use.  The `-FilterXPath` one you are using requires only the filter to be supplied.  So, your example should be:

```
$XPath = "*[System/Provider[@Name='microsoft-windows-taskscheduler'] and (System/EventID=129)]"

Get-WinEvent -logname 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational' -FilterXPath $XPath
```

The alternative is to use `-FilterXml`, which takes the full query XML you had originally (but no `-LogName` parameter):

```
$XPath = @"
  <QueryList>
    <Query Id="0" Path="microsoft-windows-taskscheduler/operational">
      <Select Path="microsoft-windows-taskscheduler/operational">*
        [System/Provider[@Name='microsoft-windows-taskscheduler'] and
        (System/EventID=129)]
      </Select>
    </Query>
  </QueryList>
"@

Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $XPath
```

Comment: I can't say why my repeated commands didn't work, but after I closed down everything and restarted, I think you keyed on something I was doing wrong...

Comment: You keyed on something I didn't realize I was doing wrong...  I was passing an `[xml]` object as the `-FilterXPath` argument.  It needs to be a string.  You inspired me to look deeper at XPath vs XML and found [this Hey Scripting Guy entry](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/06/06/understanding-xml-and-xpath/) that lays out some good rules for when to use XPath vs XML.  I can't say why my repeated commands didn't work, but after I closed down everything and started fresh with this new info, it is working again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ISE? Have you tried to close it out, open and rerun your script?

I've had similar weird issues with the ISE where it seemed it didn't want to let go of variables, etc and closing it out worked.

Comment: I do use the ISE for larger projects and syntax highlighting (i.e. it is open), but neither the successful tests nor the failing ones are being run from an ISE console; Just a straight-up PowerShell console window.